# Should a bean be initialized even if it does not have auto-wiring annotations?

Tags: spring

If I have a bean defined in an xml file like so :

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.myClass">
</bean>
```

Should "myBean" be autowired, ie should the class "com.myClass" be initialized by Spring ?

I have no Spring annotations in "com.myClass" but the class still seems to be initialized because it is declared in an xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is normal that your class to be *initialised* even though auto-wiring is not stated.  The reason for this is:

Declared Spring beans have a life-cycle and the first step in this life-cycle is for Spring to initialise the bean.

The basic life-cycle is as follows:

1. Initialise Bean
2. Insert values
3. Calling certain methods depending on which interfaces you implement.  This is useful for further custom initialisation and configuration.
4. Now your bean is ready for use by your application and will stay in the application context until your application context is destroyed.
5. Finally, if you implement the DisposableBean interface, the destroy method is called for any de-initialisation process that you may require.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether you have any other beans that want Spring to inject `myBean` into *them*. If no one uses your bean, you can omit it.